# Clarification on HTML5 alternative image files

Tags: html, image, file

Could someone please tell me precisely, for the code below,

```
<picture>
   <source media="(min-width:900px)" srcset="logo-480.png 480w, logo-768.png 768w" />  
   <img src="logo-320.png" alt="logo" sizes="(max-height: 300px) 480px" width="1000"/>
</picture>
```

under what conditions logo-480.png and logo-768.png will load?

Comment: Note that `<source>` and `<img>` do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-br-and-br-tag-in-HTML-Which-one-should-we-use

Comment: [The HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here is a reworked example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head></head><body>
   <picture>
     <source media="(min-width:2000px)" type="image/webp" srcset="logo.webp" />
     <source media="(min-width:1500px)" srcset="logo.png"/>
     <source media="(min-width:900px)"  sizes="(max-width:1200px)400px,100vw "
             srcset="logo-480-2x.png 2x, 
                     logo-768-1.5x.png 1.5x, 
                     logo-480.png 480w, 
                     logo-768.png 768w" />  
     <img src="logo-320.png" alt="logo"  sizes="(min-width: 600px) 300px, 50vw"/>
   </picture>
</body></html>
```

‘logo.webp’ will be ignored if the browser does not support webp format or the viewport width is smaller than 2000px. (resize the browser window to change the viewport size)

‘logo.png’ will get chosen if the width of the viewport is between 1500px and 2000px.

If the viewport width is between 1200px and 1500px, ‘logo-768-1.5x.png’ will be chosen because the intended width, ie. 100vw (100% viewport width, or 1200px to 1500px), is bigger than 480px and 768px, but associated with the smallest pixel density descriptor bigger than 1, ie. 1.5x. If the viewport width is between 900px and 1200px, ‘logo-480.png’ will get chosen because its width descriptor (480w) is the smallest one bigger than the intended width, 400px.

If the viewport width is smaller than 900px, ‘logo-320.png’ will be used. The ‘sizes’ attribute in  will be ignored because it is not associated with any width descriptor in an ‘srcset’ attribute.

The larger the width pixel density descriptor (eg. 2x) or the width descriptor (eg. 480w), the smaller will be the displayed image, where:
  width descriptor * pixel density descriptor = 
                                           original image width